# Is there a way to play an audio file from an array of songs by adding a play button over the song image?

Tags: reactjs

I have a music player that plays an array of songs and cycles through them using a control panel (prev, play, pause, next).

All of the song's audio files are stored in a state variable which are then called within an audio tag which is referenced using the useRef hook.
Everything is functional and hooked up to the control panel which plays when I click the play button.

I want to add the functionality to play a song when its clicked by either clicking the image or by adding a play button over top of the image. Right now songs will only play by clicking the play button which doesn't allow me to click individual songs. How would I approach this problem?

I'm thinking of maybe making the 'play' button its own component so I can use it to do this.

I have posted both the Music file and the music player component. I'm still pretty new to react so my code may not be the cleanest just yet!

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
import React from 'react'

//Components
import MusicPlayer from '../components/MusicPlayer';
import SongSlider from '../components/SongSlider';


//Song Images 
import Drake from '../images/Drake.jpg'
import Adelle from '../images/adelle.png'
import Elvis from '../images/Elvis_hounddog.jpg'
import JuiceWrld from '../images/Juicewrld.jpg'
import KingsOfLeon from '../images/Pyroalbum.jpg'
import BrittneySpears from '../images/bstoxic.jpg'
import Weeknd from '../images/starboyimg.jpg'
import LilMosey from '../images/noticed.jpg'
import ChainSmokers from '../images/chainsmokers.jpg'
import RedHotChilliPeppers from '../images/rhcp.jpg'
import TaylorSwift from '../images/TaylorSwift.jpg'

//Song files
import DrakeOneDance from '../music/Drake_One_Dance.mp3'
import AdelleHello from '../music/Adele_Hello.mp3'
import JuiceWrldLucidDreams from '../music/Lucid_Dreams.mp3'
import KingsOfLeonPyro from '../music/Pyro.mp3'
import BrittneySpearsToxic from '../music/Toxic.mp3'
import WeekndStarboy from '../music/Starboy.mp3'
import LilMoseyNoticed from '../music/Noticed.mp3'
import ChainSmokersSomething from '../music/chainsmokers.mp3'
import RhcpUnderTheBridge from '../music/Rhcp.mp3'
import TaylorSwiftLover from '../music/Taylor_Swift_Lover.mp3'
import ElvisReturnToSender from '../music/Elvis_Presley.mp3'


//Song array 

const songs = [
  
  {
    artist: 'Drake',
    songName: 'One Dance',
    poster: Drake,
    songFile: DrakeOneDance
  },
  {
    artist: 'Adelle',
    songName: 'Hello',
    poster: Adelle,
    songFile: AdelleHello
  },
  {
    artist: 'Juice Wrld',
    songName: 'Lucid Dreams',
    poster: JuiceWrld,
    songFile: JuiceWrldLucidDreams
  },
  {
    artist: 'Kings of Leon',
    songName: 'Pyro',
    poster: KingsOfLeon,
    songFile: KingsOfLeonPyro
  },
  {
    artist: 'Brittney Spears',
    songName: 'Toxic',
    poster: BrittneySpears,
    songFile: BrittneySpearsToxic
  },
  {
    artist: 'Weeknd',
    songName: 'Starboy',
    poster: Weeknd,
    songFile: WeekndStarboy
  },
  {
    artist: 'Lil Mosey',
    songName: 'Noticed',
    poster: LilMosey,
    songFile: LilMoseyNoticed
  },
  {
    artist: 'Chainsmokers',
    songName: 'Just like this',
    poster: ChainSmokers,
    songFile: ChainSmokersSomething
  },
  {
    artist: 'RHCP',
    songName: 'Under The Bridge',
    poster: RedHotChilliPeppers,
    songFile: RhcpUnderTheBridge
  },
  {
    artist: 'Taylor Swift',
    songName: 'Lover',
    poster: TaylorSwift,
    songFile: TaylorSwiftLover
  },
  {
    artist: 'Elvis',
    songName: 'Return To Sender',
    poster: Elvis,
    songFile: ElvisReturnToSender
  }

]


function Music() {

    return (

      <div className='music-container'>

        <div className="title">
            <h3>Today's Picks</h3>
        </div>
          <SongSlider songs={songs}/>
          
        <div className="title">
            <h3>Ambience</h3>
        </div>
          <MusicPlayer songs={songs}/>
      </div>
     
    );
  }

  export default Music
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

// MUI ICONS
import { Slider } from '@mui/material';
import SkipPreviousIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SkipPrevious';
import SkipNextIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SkipNext';
import PlayArrowIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PlayArrow';
import PauseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Pause';
import VolumeDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VolumeDown';
import VolumeUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VolumeUp';
import VolumeOffIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VolumeOff';
import VolumeMuteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VolumeMute';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton'



function MusicPlayer({songs}) {
    

    //Song Files
    const songFiles = songs.map(song => song.songFile)

    
    //Hooks
    const audioPlayer = useRef()

    //State
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const [currentSong] = useState(songFiles[index]);
    const [isPlaying, setisPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [volume, setVolume] = useState(30);
    const [mute, setMute] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(audioPlayer) {
            audioPlayer.current.volume = volume / 100;
        }
    }, [volume]);


    function togglePlay() {
        if(!isPlaying) {
            audioPlayer.current.play()
        } else {
            audioPlayer.current.pause()
        }
        // setisPlaying(prev => !prev)
        setisPlaying(isPlaying => !isPlaying)
    }

    function toggleSkipForward() {
        if(index >= songFiles.length - 1) {
            setIndex(0);
            audioPlayer.current.src = songFiles[0];
            audioPlayer.current.play();
        } else {
            setIndex(prev => prev + 1);
            audioPlayer.current.src = songFiles[index + 1];
            audioPlayer.current.play();
        }
    }


    function toggleSkipBackward() {
        if(index > 0) {
            setIndex(prev => prev -1);
            audioPlayer.current.src = songFiles[index -1];
            audioPlayer.current.play();
        } 
    }
    
    

    function VolumeBtns() {
        return mute
            ? <VolumeOffIcon sx={{color: 'lime', '&:hover': {color: 'white'}}} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
            : volume <= 20 ? <VolumeMuteIcon sx={{color: 'lime', '&:hover': {color: 'white'}}} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
            : volume <= 75 ? <VolumeDownIcon sx={{color: 'lime', '&:hover': {color: 'white'}}} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
            : <VolumeUpIcon sx={{color: 'lime', '&:hover': {color: 'white'}}} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
            }



  return (


    <div className='music-player-container'>

    <audio src={currentSong} ref={audioPlayer} muted={mute} />    

        <div className="controls">

            <div className="volume">

                <IconButton>
                    <VolumeBtns />
                </IconButton>

                 <Slider min={0} max={100} value={volume} onChange={(e,v) => setVolume(v)}
                defaultValue={50}
                    sx={{
                    width: 100,
                    color: 'success.main',
                    margin: '20px',
                    }} /> 
            </div>

            <div className="control-panel">

                    <IconButton onClick={toggleSkipBackward}>
                        <SkipPreviousIcon
                        sx={{
                            margin: '10px',
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            color: 'silver', '&:hover': {color: 'blue'}
                        }} />
                    </IconButton>

                    {/* Play/Pause */}
                
                {!isPlaying
                  ?  <IconButton onClick={togglePlay}>
                        <PlayArrowIcon sx={{ margin: '10px', cursor: 'pointer', color: 'silver', '&:hover': {color: 'blue'} }} />
                    </IconButton>
                    
                   : <IconButton onClick={togglePlay}>
                        <PauseIcon sx={{ margin: '10px', cursor: 'pointer', color: 'silver', '&:hover': {color: 'blue'} }} />
                    </IconButton>
                }
                    
                    {/* Play/Pause */}


                    <IconButton onClick={toggleSkipForward}>
                        <SkipNextIcon
                        sx={{
                            margin: '10px',
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            color: 'silver', '&:hover': {color: 'blue'}
                        }} />
                    </IconButton>

            </div>
        </div>
                         
            
    </div>


  )
}

export default MusicPlayer
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think making the play button a component is a good idea : you'll be able to use it where you want and how you want. The idea is to play your song via a method (togglePlay(), I guess?).

I'd say that having a "songID" parameter in this method could be great to locate your song and play it. (And also to make it more flexible for your future modifications : always think about your next move, do a drawing of what you want and make sure to think about it before doign anything. You'll save some time and that's an experience tip ahah.)

Devingly,
Marceau.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).